# How to add an existing widget to Nopcommerce?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, nopcommerce-3.90

I am really new to Nopcommerce. I have an existing plugin [A slider widget for homepage]. I was trying to add the Nop.Plugin.Widget.PromoSlider.csproj file in the Plugins directory from Visual Studio 17 but got the following error:

> The imported project
>   "S(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was
>   not found. Also, tried to find
>   "S(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Mlicrosoft.WebApplication.targets" in
>   the fallback search path(s) for $(VSToolsPath) - "C:\Program
>   Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0" These search paths
>   are defined in "C:\Users***\AppData\Local\
>   Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_f96fcd52\devenv.exe.config". Confirm that
>   the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file
>   exists on disk in one of the search paths. C:\Users****\Deskctop\
>   Nop.Plugin.Widget.PromoSlider\Nop.Plugin.Widget.PromoSlider.csproj

Can anyone help me fix this error?

Comment: `Nop.Plugin.Widget.PromoSlider.csproj` is it an exiting plugin? are you copying from different solutnion?

Comment: Yes, It is from different nopcommerce solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to add a visual studio 2015 project in visual studio 2017. There is a ongoing investigation on this issue. But there is a workaround on this as well. Please check [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27735/project-fails-to-load-with-error-regarding-microso.html) for more details.

One work around is changing the following line (editing `Nop.Plugin.Widget.PromoSlider.csproj`)

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

to

```
<Import Project="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Give it a try